# Se puede pasar el texto de una textbox a el string del comando Process.Start?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, textbox

primero que nada una disculpa si no me llego a explicar del todo bien, estoy haciendo mi primer programa con ayuda de tutoriales, es una api en windows forms con lenguaje c#. Estoy trabado en una parte ya que lo que deseo que haga mi programa es que al presionar un "button" este ejecute el comando System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path"); para arrancar ejecutables .exe

hay alguna manera de pasar la **ruta registrada en el textbox del archivo que deseo abrir**  al **"path" del System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()**?

Muchas gracias de antemano y espero haber explicado mi problema bien.

Answer (score 0):

Claro que se puede , debes usar el siguiente código:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(nombredeltextbox.Text);
```

Comment: No seria nombre del textbox en lugar de nombre del boton, revisa bien eso

Comment: tenes razon, pense que era un boton, mil disculpas

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera:
Uso el `UseShellExecute` para especificarle que use el shell de Windows.
Y el `WindowStyle` para ocultar la ventana del shell en caso de no necesitarla.

En `p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"File.exe")` puedes agregar la ruta del archivo .exe, para que ejecute, pero asegúrate de poner una buena ruta que no sea afectada cuando ejecutes el proyecto.

```
try
{
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"File.exe")
    {
        UseShellExecute = true,
        WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };

    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception ex){}
```

Pero aquí viene el dilema, para que se ejecute bien tengo que tener el archivo .exe dentro del directorio de ejecución del proyecto. Porque cuando ejecutas el proyecto las rutas de acceso cambian.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]